# Audio graph initialization error with kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO audio IO unit subtype

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, voip

I am working on a iOS project that needs acoustic echo cancelation so the kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO subtype seems to be a good choice.
Below is my audio unit description

```
//io unit description 
AudioComponentDescription ioUnitDescription;
ioUnitDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
ioUnitDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO;
ioUnitDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
ioUnitDescription.componentFlags = 0;
ioUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0;
```

And based on my experience with RemoteIO subtype, I enabled the input element:

```
UInt32  enable = 1;
AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &enable, sizeof(enable));
```

However, I got error when initializing the audio graph. The same audio graph works well if the VoiceProcessingIO is replaced by RemoteIO.

Is there any difference between RemoteIO and VoiceProcessingIO that needs special attention?

Thanks,
Chuankai

Comment: sorry to comment on an only question but have you figure out echo cancellation ? The apple docs keep referring to voice processing IO having this feature but I can't find an example of it anywhere. I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the VoiceProcessingIO audio unit is much more finicky regarding buffer size and sample rate.  Try a sample rate below 32000 Hz (perhaps start with 8000 Hz and make your way upward) and a fairly large buffer size (say 2048 samples or so). This is not documented.  rdar number to come once I have a chance to file one.

I use the following format during set-up:

```
    size_t bytesPerSample = sizeof(AudioSampleType);
    AudioStreamBasicDescription canonicalFormat;
    canonicalFormat.mSampleRate         = self.samplerate;
    canonicalFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    canonicalFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
    canonicalFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    canonicalFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
    canonicalFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 8 * bytesPerSample;
    canonicalFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = bytesPerSample;
    canonicalFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = bytesPerSample;
```